# How to "zoom in" one level with Google maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I can't find an answer for that simple question anywhere!
How on earth can we zoom in with one level (+1 from the current one) in google maps API V3?

I mean is there a function for that purpose? or a hack or whatever?

What I actually want to do is to zoom by one level onclick on a link located in a marker's infowindow and also the same result `ondblclick` on the marker but in both cases the zoom should increment only +1 at each event (click on link or `dblclick` on marker) and the zoom center should be the marker in question.

I'm open to any suggestion involving native Googlemaps methods, jQuery or plain Javascript.

Anyone who tickled the same problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());    //marker is marker to center on
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
```